# How to apply a settimeout in the VUEJS script?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, settimeout

I am developing my first application in vuejs and in the initial data upload in the script I need to modify the data I received from a call to the database.
Since I have modified the data it returns an error in the initial load of the page and after a few seconds it loads without problem.
I am trying to wrap this function in a settimeout but it returns an error in vuejs.
How can I apply this setTimeout?

here my script

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        step: 1,
        selected: 1
      }
    },
    components: {

    },
    computed:{
      selectedBasket() {
        
        return !this.$store.getters.basket ? null : this.$store.getters.basket
      },
      items(){
        return !this.$store.getters.items ? null : this.$store.getters.items
      },
      setTimeout(() => {
       filteredEstimation(){
        this.$store.getters.estimations.map(function(estimation) {
          estimation.offers.map(function(offer) {
            offer.name = offer.name.split(" ").reverse().slice(1).reverse().join(" ");
            if (offer.name.includes("first")) {
              offer.description = "first option";
            }
            if (offer.name.includes("second")) {
              offer.description = "second option";
            }
            if (offer.name.includes("third")) {
              offer.description = "third option";
            }
          });
        });
        return !this.$store.getters.estimations ? null : this.$store.getters.estimations.filter( item => item.id == this.selected )[0].offers
      }, 700);
    },
    methods: {
      getItemsName(item) {

        if(item == 1){
          return 'bag'
        } else if(item == 2){
          return 'paper'
        } else {
          return 'pen'
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using that function inside the computed option, that's not allowed, you should define it in the mounted hook like :

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        step: 1,
        selected: 1
      }
    },
    components: {

    },
    computed:{
      selectedBasket() {
        
        return !this.$store.getters.basket ? null : this.$store.getters.basket
      },
      items(){
        return !this.$store.getters.items ? null : this.$store.getters.items
      },
    },
    methods: {
      getItemsName(item) {

        if(item == 1){
          return 'bag'
        } else if(item == 2){
          return 'paper'
        } else {
          return 'pen'
        }
      }
    },
  mounted(){

      setTimeout(() => {
       filteredEstimation(){
        this.$store.getters.estimations.map(function(estimation) {
          estimation.offers.map(function(offer) {
            offer.name = offer.name.split(" ").reverse().slice(1).reverse().join(" ");
            if (offer.name.includes("first")) {
              offer.description = "first option";
            }
            if (offer.name.includes("second")) {
              offer.description = "second option";
            }
            if (offer.name.includes("third")) {
              offer.description = "third option";
            }
          });
        });
        return !this.$store.getters.estimations ? null : this.$store.getters.estimations.filter( item => item.id == this.selected )[0].offers
      }, 700);

  }
  }
</script>
```